# RSA congruence (n is not given)

Tags: rsa, congruence

it might be a silly question but i need help please

given RSA system , where $n=pq , p\ and \ q \ are \ primes $ , $ v_0,v_1,v_2, v_3 \ are \ known $

> $p^p \equiv v_0 \mod q$
>
> $q^q \equiv v_1 \mod p$
>
> $q^p + p^q \equiv v_2 \mod pq$
>
> $(p+q)^{p+q}  \equiv v_3 \mod pq$
>
> Mathmatical facts:
>
> $p^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod q$
>
> is obtained using $\phi(q)=q-1$ , Fermat: $p^{\phi(q)} \equiv 1 \mod q$
>
> $q^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$
>
> $q^p + p^q \equiv p+q \mod pq$
>
> is obtained using $(p^{q} \equiv p \mod pq) + (q^{p} \equiv q \mod pq)$
>
> $(p+q)^{p+q}  \equiv p^{p+q}+ q^{p+q}  \mod pq$

Edit : The solution from https://ctf-wiki.github.io/ctf-wiki/crypto/asymmetric/rsa/rsa_theory/#2018-national-security-week-pure-math

is $q=\frac{v_3-v_0*v2}{v_1-v_0}$ where you can rewrite as

$q=\frac{p^{p+q}+ q^{p+q} -p^p*(q^p + p^q)}{q^q-p^p}= \frac{p^{p+q}+ q^{p+q} -p^{p+q}-(pq)^p }{q^q-p^p}= \frac{q^{p}*(q^q-p^p) }{q^q-p^p} = q^p = q $

I can prove this backward how is calculated but what is the fundamental idea that used to bring the above equation?

Comment: I voted to close this, because it is just a copy&paste of the homework question.

Comment: It is not homework question, a hint will be helpful

Comment: The issue is not, if this was an actual homework assignment to you specifically. The issue is, you just copied the question and wrote "help me" - with 0 effort from your side. At the very least, you should state what you tried and where you got stuck. If you did not do that: Try on your own first.

Comment: A hint to get you started: Write $p=q+a$ and replace all $p$ with that. And use the laws you were given below, while respecting the different modulus. It should be obvious, where you can apply which rule. BTW: I don't know if it works, it's just an idea. Without any effort on your side, I don't see a reason to think about this much.